# Getting com.sun.jdi.InvocationException: Exception occurred in target VM occurred invoking method Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am writing a UI automation code wherein I am trying to wait for an element to load i.e. visibility of an element but getting a null pointer exception. When I tried to debug, I found that the element value being passed is "com.sun.jdi.InvocationException: Exception occurred in target VM occurred invoking method" hence I am getting null pointer.

I am not aware what this error is and I am stuck.

Below is my code.

`

```
public static void waitForElementToLoad(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, int waitTimeInSeconds) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,waitTimeInSeconds);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    }
```

`

The argument element says Invocation exception. The method where I am calling this method is
`

```
public void waitForShareHolderInputScreenToLoad() {
        WaitActions.waitForElementToLoad(driver, complexityComboBox, Utils.EXPLICIT_WAIT_VALUE_LONG);
    }
```

`

The locator complexityComboBox is as follows.
`

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@role='combobox']/span")
    private static WebElement complexityComboBox;
```

`

Not getting what exactly is the issue here.

Comment: debug and check complexityComboBox value.  It may be null.  (If the element doesn't exist yet, it'll throw no such element exception and I don't think it'll ever intialize.)  The webdriverwait should be added to the findby....

Comment: I tried debugging and found the same. The complexity combo box element value is shown as the exception value

Comment: I'd add the webdriverwait to the findby annotations/methods... you should try/catch there so you can deal with any timeout exceptions thrown.